# JPA query, ArgumentException

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

i am trying to query two database tables using a result class with the following query:

```
public List<UserStatus> getUserStatus(String username) {
   String qlString = 
           "SELECT NEW no.uia.slit.ejb.UserStatus(file.filename, file.uploadTime, mod.title, mod.dueAt) "
           + "FROM DownloadableFile file, Module mod"
           + "where file.moduleId = mod.id";
   TypedQuery<UserStatus> query = em.createQuery(qlString, UserStatus.class);
   return query.getResultList();
```

}

Running this i get the following error:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.3.0-nonfinal-1540826-r422266:1542644 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Encountered "mod ." at character 71, but expected: ["(", "+", "-", ":", "?", "ABS", "AVG", "CASE", "COALESCE", "CONCAT", "COUNT", "CURRENT_DATE", "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "ENTRY", "INDEX", "KEY", "LENGTH", "LOCATE", "LOWER", "MAX", "MIN", "MOD", "NULLIF", "SIZE", "SQRT", "SUBSTRING", "SUM", "TRIM", "TYPE", "UPPER", "VALUE", <BOOLEAN_LITERAL>, <DATE_LITERAL>, <DECIMAL_LITERAL>, <IDENTIFIER>, <INTEGER_LITERAL>, <STRING_LITERAL2>, <STRING_LITERAL>, <TIMESTAMP_LITERAL>, <TIME_LITERAL>].
```

My result class is as follows:

```
public class UserStatus {

private String title;
private Date dueAt;
private String filename;
private Timestamp uploadTime;
public UserStatus(){
    super();
}
public UserStatus(String filename, Timestamp uploadTime, String title, Date dueAt) {
    this.filename = filename;
    this.uploadTime = uploadTime;
    this.title = title;
    this.dueAt = dueAt;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setDueAt(Date dueAt) {
    this.dueAt = dueAt;
}
public Date getDueAt() {
    return dueAt;
}

public void setFileName(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return filename;
}

public void setUploadTime(Timestamp uploadTime) {
    this.uploadTime = uploadTime;
}

public Timestamp getUploadTime() {
    return uploadTime;
}
```

}

i used an example i found to make the query and i cant figure out what is wrong, i know it says "mod . " is wrong but why.

edit: https://blogs.oracle.com/adf/entry/ejb_dc_using_jpql_constructor this is the example i used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"MOD" is a reserved keyword used by the JPQL language, so you can't use it for your variable names. Pick some other name not in that list

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, that worked. Stupid mistake should read documentation better from now on..

Answer (score 1):

`mod` ([ducumentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod)) is a reserved word in sql change it to `module` and it should work